Is there a solution for this diophantine equation
$$
\prod_{k=0}^n(q_k^2-1)=a^2-1
$$
for $q_k \in \mathbb{N}\quad \forall  k \leq n$ and $a \in \mathbb{N}$

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

What about $q_k=1$ and $a=1$?

Can $q_k$ be equal to zero? :-)

$5^2-1=(3^2-1)(2^2-1)$

$11^2-1=(4^2-1)(3^2-1).$

If $a$ is even, $n$ must be odd.

If $a$ is even, neither $a-1$ nor $a+1$ can be prime.

As Thomas Andrews pointed out, $(m^2-1)((m+1)^2-1)+1=(m^2+m-1)^2=a^2$

You need to split between the cases $n$ even and $n$ odd:
$n$ even (like $n=6$):
$$a^2-1 = (0^2-1) \times (0^2-1) \times (0^2-1) \times (0^2-1) \times (\sqrt{a}^2-1) \times (\sqrt{a}^2+1)$$
=> So, if $a$ is a perfect square, no problem.
$n$ odd (like $n=7$):
$$a^2 - 1 = (0^2-1) \times (0^2-1) \times (0^2-1) \times (0^2-1) \times (0^2-1) \times (0^2-1) \times (a^2-1)$$
So, what about the cases where $a$ is not a perfect square and $n$ is even? That's the real question!
